# Dealing with interpolated values in web scraping (Beautiful Soup)

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm doing some web scraping with Python and Beautiful Soup.

I've encountered a problem where the results I'm getting contain the raw Javascript interpolations, rather than the values themselves.

So instead of the

`<span>2.4%</span>`

which I can see in the Chrome inspector, I instead get:

`<span> {{ item.rate }} </span>`

with my result from beautiful soup.

a) Am I doing something wrong (similar code works on a different website so I don't think so but might be wrong)?

or

b) Is there a way of dealing with this?

My code:

```
url = "https://example.com"
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
divs = soup.findAll("ul", {"class": "result-table--grid"})
print(div[0])
```

Thank you!

Comment: my guess is the page is dynamic. That value may be stored in the script tags, or possibly can be accessed through an api request url. is it possible to share the url?

Comment: Aha, makes sense. The url is https://www.moneysupermarket.com/mortgages/results/#?goal=1&property=170000&borrow=150000&types=1&types=2&types=3&types=4&types=5

Comment: I provided code below to pull that data. The other option is you could also use Selenium to render the page first, and THEN pull the html source as you are doing already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the json format response in this way below. then using `json_normalize`. Now doing this you'll see there are nexted lists/dictionaries in the columns. So I'll offer a 2nd solution that flattens those out too, but it's going to really extend out your table horizontally

**Code 1**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
import pandas as pd

url = "https://www.moneysupermarket.com/mortgages/results/#?goal=1&property=170000&borrow=150000&types=1&types=2&types=3&types=4&types=5"

request_url = 'https://www.moneysupermarket.com/bin/services/aggregation'

headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.36'}

payload = {
'channelId': '55',
'enquiryId': '2e619c17-061a-4812-adad-40a9f9d8dcbc',
'limit': '20',
'offset': '0',
'sort': 'initialMonthlyPayment'}


jsonObj = requests.get(request_url, headers=headers, params = payload).json()

results = pd.DataFrame()
for each in jsonObj['results']:
    temp_df = json_normalize(each['quote'])
    results = results.append(temp_df).reset_index(drop=True)
```

**Output 1:**

```
print (results)
                                               @class                        ...                                                         trackerDescription
0   com.moneysupermarket.mortgages.entity.Mortgage...                        ...                                                                           
1   com.moneysupermarket.mortgages.entity.Mortgage...                        ...                                                                           
2   com.moneysupermarket.mortgages.entity.Mortgage...                        ...                                                                           
3   com.moneysupermarket.mortgages.entity.Mortgage...                        ...                                                                           
4   com.moneysupermarket.mortgages.entity.Mortgage...                        ...                                                                           
5   com.moneysupermarket.mortgages.entity.Mortgage...                        ...                                                                           
6   com.moneysupermarket.mortgages.entity.Mortgage...                        ...                                                                           
7   com.moneysupermarket.mortgages.entity.Mortgage...                        ...                                                                           
8   com.moneysupermarket.mortgages.entity.Mortgage...                        ...                                                                           
9   com.moneysupermarket.mortgages.entity.Mortgage...                        ...                                                                           
10  com.moneysupermarket.mortgages.entity.Mortgage...                        ...                                                                           
11  com.moneysupermarket.mortgages.entity.Mortgage...                        ...                                                                           
12  com.moneysupermarket.mortgages.entity.Mortgage...                        ...                                                                           
13  com.moneysupermarket.mortgages.entity.Mortgage...                        ...                                                                           
14  com.moneysupermarket.mortgages.entity.Mortgage...                        ...                                                                           
15  com.moneysupermarket.mortgages.entity.Mortgage...                        ...                          after 26 Months,BBR + 3.99% for the remaining ...
16  com.moneysupermarket.mortgages.entity.Mortgage...                        ...                                                                           
17  com.moneysupermarket.mortgages.entity.Mortgage...                        ...                                                                           
18  com.moneysupermarket.mortgages.entity.Mortgage...                        ...                                                                           
19  com.moneysupermarket.mortgages.entity.Mortgage...                        ...                          after 26 Months,BBR + 3.99% for the remaining ...

[20 rows x 51 columns]
```

**Code 2:**

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = "https://www.moneysupermarket.com/mortgages/results/#?goal=1&property=170000&borrow=150000&types=1&types=2&types=3&types=4&types=5"

request_url = 'https://www.moneysupermarket.com/bin/services/aggregation'
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.36'}
payload = {
'channelId': '55',
'enquiryId': '2e619c17-061a-4812-adad-40a9f9d8dcbc',
'limit': '20',
'offset': '0',
'sort': 'initialMonthlyPayment'}

data = requests.get(request_url, headers=headers, params = payload).json()

def flatten_json(y):
    out = {}
    def flatten(x, name=''):
        if type(x) is dict:
            for a in x:
                flatten(x[a], name + a + '_')
        elif type(x) is list:
            i = 0
            for a in x:
                flatten(a, name + str(i) + '_')
                i += 1
        else:
            out[name[:-1]] = x
    flatten(y)
    return out


results = pd.DataFrame()
for each in data['results']:
    flat = flatten_json(each)
    temp_df = pd.DataFrame([flat], columns = flat.keys())

    results = results.append(temp_df).reset_index(drop=True)
```

**Output 2:**

```
print (results)
    apply_active  apply_desktop   ...    straplineLinkLabel  topTip
0           True           True   ...                  None    None
1           True           True   ...                  None    None
2           True           True   ...                  None    None
3           True           True   ...                  None    None
4           True           True   ...                  None    None
5           True           True   ...                  None    None
6           True           True   ...                  None    None
7           True           True   ...                  None    None
8           True           True   ...                  None    None
9           True           True   ...                  None    None
10          True           True   ...                  None    None
11          True           True   ...                  None    None
12          True           True   ...                  None    None
13          True           True   ...                  None    None
14          True           True   ...                  None    None
15          True           True   ...                  None    None
16          True           True   ...                  None    None
17          True           True   ...                  None    None
18          True           True   ...                  None    None
19          True           True   ...                  None    None

[20 rows x 131 columns]
```